# HTML Check box can be checked but :checked psuedo class doesn't register it

Tags: css

I have a checkbox that when it is clicked, it's meant to move my nav bar to the left, but nothing happenes. I've checked the property in F12 (Chrome) and when I check the box, the checked property stays false. Any ideas? Code is below.

```
#toggle:checked + .nav-links {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #009af3;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 4;
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

.

```
                <nav>
                    <div class="logo-container">
                        <img src="/images/Business/logo.png" alt="LPS Logo">
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav-links">
                        <li><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Production</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Dry Hire</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Installation</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="burger">
                        <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
                    </div>
                </nav>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Showing just the CSS alone is not very helpful, we need to see the HTML it gets applied to as well. Guess here would be that you simply do not have a HTML structure that allows to select the elements in this way.

Comment: Show us the HTML code too

Comment: without the full code, we cant help

Comment: Sorry completely forgot, HTML has been added!

Comment: This is because a `+` in CSS means the next following element. You don't have any following element after your checkbox. So it can never show your navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in CSS you use `+` which means apply this to all rules that are next to in your case `toggle`-Element. So to actually see the navigation you have to move it next to the toggle-element in the HTML:

```css
#toggle:checked+.nav-links {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.nav-links {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #009af3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 4;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img src="/images/Business/logo.png" alt="LPS Logo">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Production</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Dry Hire</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Installation</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="burger">
    <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The burger element can stay where it is, just the input needs to be moved before the UL. (Via the `for` attribute, the label can toggle the checkbox from anywhere, and the checkbox itself is likely going to get hidden anyway.)

Comment: you are right, of course :) I will update the HTML with this suggestion.